# Counting values in the same level of a multidemensional array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to count how many of the same calendar weeks I have inside the same level of a multidimensional array. My start array can be seen on the picture on the left part, my output is composed of an ID [0] and the rest are the dates corresponding to that ID. 
On my code I convert these dates to calendar weeks and then try to count them with a foreach loop and then unset the last values if they are identical to the newest ones, so that I only have the final count. My Problem is that as you can see on the last array [1975]->1->1 the count is not right, it is taking in count also the same weeks from the other ID.
Any kind of help is much appreciated!

[image: DD from my arrays]

My code looks like this:

```
$array= array();
$arrayCount=array();
$j=0;
foreach ($sorted as $value) {
  $k=1;
  foreach ($value[1] as $match) {
    $time = strtotime($match);
    $Calendar_Week = date('W',$time);
    $Year = date('Y',$time);
    if(!array_key_exists($Calendar_Week , $array)){
              $i=1;
              $array[$Calendar_Week][$j]=$match;
      }
    $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][0]=$sorted[$j][0];
    $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k][]=$i;
    $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k][]=$Calendar_Week;
    $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k][]=$Year;
    // Delete previous counts of the same value
    if ($arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k-1][1]==$Calendar_Week & $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k-1][2]==$Year) {
              unset($arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k-1]);
    }
    $i++;
    $k++;
  }
  $j++;

}
dd($sorted, $arrayCount);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to reset the $i and $array inside the  foreach loop

```
$i=1;
$array = array();
```

Please check this code

```
$array= array();
$arrayCount=array();
$j=0;

foreach ($sorted as $value) {
    $k=1;
    $i=1;
    $array = array();
    foreach ($value[1] as $match) {
        $time = strtotime($match);
        $Calendar_Week = date('W',$time);
        $Year = date('Y',$time);
        if(!array_key_exists($Calendar_Week , $array)){
                $i=1;
                $array[$Calendar_Week][$j]=$match;
        }
        $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][0]=$sorted[$j][0];
        $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k][]=$i;
        $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k][]=$Calendar_Week;
        $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k][]=$Year;
        // Delete previous counts of the same value
        if ($arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k-1][1]==$Calendar_Week & $arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k-1][2]==$Year) {
                unset($arrayCount[$sorted[$j][0]][1][$k-1]);
        }
        $i++;
        $k++;
    }
    $j++;
}
dd($sorted, $arrayCount);
```